# Dynamically changing UI using merge and include tags depending on click

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to android and programming in general so go easy!

I have created a - probably overcomplicated but it does what I want - main.xml with my layout which goes something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<LinearLayout
    ...
    >
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:gravity="center"
    />
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="0"
        >
        <TableRow>
            <TextView/>
            <Spinner/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView/>
            <Spinner/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_tablelayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/price0"
        />
        <TableRow>
            <TextView/>
            <EditText/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is one of the options that I'm trying to include (price1.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/price1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/price1"
    />
</TableRow> 
</merge>
```

I am trying to dynamically change the include depending on what value one of the spinners has, but I get a force close on starting the app.

The logcat error is:

```
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1871)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:421)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1828)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:403)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1808)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:394)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at com.kavi.eta.Calculate$1.onItemSelected(Calculate.java:36)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:42)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:837)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-18 15:31:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Looks like I'm doing the java code wrong but I can't figure out how to properly remove the default include and replace it with another layout:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) { 
            int index = formatSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            if (index == 0) {

                TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_tablelayout2);
                tl.removeView(findViewById(R.id.include));

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                tl.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.price1, tl, true));
            }
```

Sorry about the long post but I've searched everywhere and can't find a clear answer. Hopefully this'll at least provide a decent-ish example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't really find a proper solution to this, but for completeness, this is what I ended up doing:
I kept getting a NullPointerException when using findViewById for any of the views in the price1.xml (ie The xml being included). Is this by design?
This was a problem as I had to dynamically add/remove certain views depending on the user input.

I still have an include tag in my main.xml, which I remove by looking up the position relative to it's parent (again, I couldn't get the findViewById to work but this just as effetive). I then inflate another xml file in it's place, depending on the user input.

```
if (position == 0) {
                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_linearlayout);
                    ll.removeViewAt(3);
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    ll.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.replacement1, null), 3);

                } else if (position == 1) {
                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_linearlayout);
                    ll.removeViewAt(3);
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    ll.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.replacement2, null), 3);
```

I have also cleaned up my main.xml to remove unnecessary nesting of layouts and ditched the merge tags and used TableLayout as the root tags for my included xml.
That seems to be my UI troubles sorted (for now!)...

Answer (score 1):

You'll get `NullPointerException` if you'll try to use `findViewById()` on elements present inside the included layout. They are not in the layout which is added in `setContentView(View)`, so You've to give your include tag and id such as includedLayout, in following code snippet -

```
<include android:id="@+id/includedLayout" layout="@layout/yourLayout"/>
```

and finding it using the normal findViewById() call

```
ViewGroup includedLayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.includedLayout);
```

and then using this object to find views inside the included layout.

```
View myVIew = includedLayout.findViewById(R.id.myViewId);
```

Although the thread is old, but I guess this answer will help future readers to find exactly what's going on in their layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also quite new, but maybe it helps:

You could give removing the  a try. I don't think this tag is appropiate in this case because you won't have two layouts of the same kind directly nested either way.
Although I wouldn't expect an IllegalStateException in this case.

Are you adding Views in your onCreate()?

Comment: All I've got in onCreate() is setContentView(R.layout.main);
and I populate my Spinners using an adapter.

All adding of views is done in the XML through setContentView(R.layout.main);

I think you missed out a crucial component in your suggestion! "You could give removing the ??? a try."

Comment: was there a difference when you removed the <merge />?

Comment: I can't remove the merge without putting in another layout as the root, which I don't want to do because it messes with my alignment of the boxes by nesting another ViewGroup...

EDIT: Tried removing it anyway and still had the same problem. I thought the whole point of <merge> is that it's essentially "invisible" anyway?

Comment: The XML Parser does essentially skip the merge tag, that is correct.
Does it work without the include? All I can read from the logcat is that you are trying to add a child to a parent which only accepts one child and this is already set!
If it is the same without the include you have to look through your xml for that! But once again, i would expect another Exception in that case.

Comment: It seems that the <merge> was overriding the id from the <include> so the view wasn't being removed to begin with.
I got it to work by removing the <merge> from my price1.xml and putting the xmlns line inside the <TableRow> but I wasn't happy with the way it was working. The layout was looking messy and wasn't very efficient, with too many nested ViewGroups, so I've cleaned up my main.xml.
Looks like I'll still be using <include> somewhere so I'll post up my final results when I'm done. It'll be more of a workaround than an answer to my original question!